# Прогноз вне выборки. Как реализовать?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

Задавал вопрос о прогнозе вне выборки, но ответов нет.
Может на простом примере будет понятнее.
Пример.
Есть данные:
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
Потом. Нормализации данных. Подготовка на вход.
Работа НС (бух-бах, волшебство)
Инверсия данных.
Выход.
Следующий элемент должен быть. [9.98743]
Это грубый пример.
Сколько не смотрел примеров, везде только прогноз в выборке. То есть тестовых данных.
А реализация прогноза вне выборки мне не понятен.
Накидайте пожалуйста ссылок.
Можно пример привести.
Как такое реализовать?

Спасибо за ответ.
Но я хотел узнать как реализовать предсказание на элементы вне выборки.
Вот например в данном коде. Как узнать загрязнение на следующий день или следующую неделю или следующий месяц.
Как сама функция этого реализуется?
Не могу найти примеры такой реализации.

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import concatenate
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
 
# convert series to supervised learning
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg
 
# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:,4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:,4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, 1, 1)
# drop columns we don't want to predict
reframed.drop(reframed.columns[[9,10,11,12,13,14,15]], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(reframed.head())
 
# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
 
# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# plot history
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
 
# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], test_X.shape[2]))
# invert scaling for forecast
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:,0]
# calculate RMSE
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_y, inv_yhat))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

Вот пример с гитхаба, но и здесь, и в других примерах, которые я видел, реализован только прогноз по выборке, а вне выборки нету.

Comment: Ну вам просто нужно сделать `test_X` дальше, после выборки, на которой учитесь. И если модель правильно натренирована, то на таком `X` предскажется правильный `y`. Вопрос только в том, как вы учили модель, какие у вас данные. С временными рядами обычно приходится по одному шажочку предсказывать, потому что модель предсказывает на ближайшее время. Хотя специальные модели вроде `facebook profet` умеют это делать "под капотом", им не нужно по одному шагу данные для предсказания кормить, можно сразу диапазон предсказывать.

Comment: Так я делал Test_X.  и НС предсказывает последний день тестовой выборки. А следующий не как не хочет.

Comment: @Antonio0608 а покажите, как вы задавали НС требование сделать прогноз на данных которые НЕ входят в Test_X ?

Answer (score 2):

Любая модель машинного обучения / нейронных сетей всегда ожидает на вход данные в определенном формате или, говоря техническим языком, тензор одной и той же размерности, не учитывая первую или последнюю ось (количество образцов). Например если у вас набор данных в виде 2D матрицы или таблицы, то модель всегда будет ожидать одинаковое количество столбцов. Число строк может различаться.

Данные вне выборки это те данные, которые вы получите на вход **в будущем**. Для того чтобы натренировать и протестировать такую модель делают следующим образом:

1. берется достаточно большая выборка данных
2. разбивается на две части - обучающая и тестовая выборки
3. если речь идет о временном ряде то в качестве тестовой выборки обычно берут последние (по времени) 20-30% данных. Если это не временной ряд, тогда данные перемешивают случайным образом и делят на две части - 70-80% на обучения, остальное на тесты.
4. дальше обучаем модель на обучающем наборе, а точность модели проверяем на тестовом наборе данных.
5. когда мы довольны результатами тестов, модель выкатывается в продакшн и начинает работать на совершенно новых данных. Разумеется все шаги препроцессинга (пред-обработки), которые вы делали для обучающей и тестовой выборок, нужно повторить и для новых входных данных.
6. после этого ее модель обычно дообучают на новых данных

Вот как-то так...